# What is the recommended USB software to put an ISO of Ubuntu on USB?

Tags: boot, usb

I've used Rufus and the Universal USB from pendrivelinux, but I was wondering if there's a recommended software or if there is a better one.

Answer (score 3):

The best application for making a bootable Ubuntu live USB from Ubuntu is the built-in Startup Disk Creator application because it is the most reliable of all such applications.

The best application for making a bootable Ubuntu live USB from Windows is [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/). The official ubuntu.com website recommends using Rufus instead of UNetbootin. Step-by-step instructions for creating a bootable Ubuntu live USB from Windows are at [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

Rufus persistent storage partition is supported in 19.10 and later. Please upgrade Rufus to version 3.9 or later.

[image: Rufus persistent storage]

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using DD from command line like `sudo dd if=/path/to/file.iso of=/dev/USB_DRIVE` this works like a charm and comes preinstalled with most systems.

Comment: It will probably require `sudo` ; and an alternative is to use `cat`, as in `sudo cat file.iso >/dev/USB_DRIVE`

Comment: Thank you, forgot that `sudo` ;) Added now!

Comment: Note: make sure you provide valid path of .iso file , if not may lead  to loss of valuable data.@gotta-ask-fast